# Touchscreen unresponsive on 4.4-rc7, but works on 4.2. cat /dev/hidraw0 doesn't show anything

Tags: touch-screen, hid

I'm testing out kernel 4.4-rc7 (same problem with rc5), but can't get laptop touchscreen to work. It's an Asus TP200SA.

```
kernel4.4-rc7 $ dmesg | grep hid
[    2.741654] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    7.128672] hid-multitouch 0018:0457:1136.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Device [SIS0457:00 0457:1136] on i2c-SIS0457:00
```

So far, I can't see any significant difference between logs. But when I do a `cat /dev/input/event10`, kernel 4.2 actually produces outputs in response to my touch taps, while 4.4-rc* do not. I know it's event10 because (a) no other event responds either and (b) I can do `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` and it produces:

```
[...]
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0457 Product=1136 Version=0100
N: Name="SIS0457:00 0457:1136"
P: Phys=i2c-SIS0457:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:05/i2c-13/i2c-SIS0457:00/0018:0457:1136.0001/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event10 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
```

The same is for `cat /dev/hidraw0`. Produces output for 4.2, but not 4.4-rc7. Let me know if more info will help. Thanks!

**Edit**: The devices were hidraw1/event9 in 4.2, the numbers changed because of something to do with the elan_i2c module touchpad (which is working fine).

**Edit2**: Just checked with kernel 4.3. Screen was still functional. Something broke between 4.3 and 4.4-rc7. I am pouring through kernel source diff for `device/hid` to see if anything is amiss. That's where the module hid_multitouch lives.